# Trouble with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Whenever I create a new JUnit Test Case it generates like this:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;


public class Test extends TestCase {

}
```

But this isn't correct. There isn't even an @Test generated, and when I put it in myself I get a type mismatch error (cannot convert from Test to annotation). Any help?

Edit:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


public class Test {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Comment: "I create a new JUnit Test Case", How are you generating test cases? Are you using an IDE? If so please mention that in your question.

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse.

Comment: May be you are using old version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the right version of JUnit. Check the version you are using. Annotations are available in JUnit 4 and not available in JUnit 3

Comment: Under:

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries

In the window it has:

> JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]
> JUnit 3
> JUnit 4

Comment: Not sure if I understood right. But if you have option to remove JUnit 3, do so. Have only JUnit 4

Comment: Yes, your latest edit shows the right annotation used in JUnit 4